# CSS3 Rounded Corners are not working in IE quirks mode

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I have a website which works perfectly in IE 10 as Browser mode and IE5 quirks as document mode. But the round corners are not working in this scenario. Rounded corners are working when i change the document mode to IE 9 standards. But i want IE 5 quirks as document mode.

My CSS is:

```
.roundedcorner
{
    behavior: url(/Includes/border-radius.htc);
    -moz-border-radius: 30px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 30px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 30px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    border-top-left-radius:30px;
    border-top-right-radius:30px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:30px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:30px;
}
```

Comment: When you say: "Please render in an ancient crusty document mode that doesn't follow current standards" you shouldn't expect to be able to use modern standards like CSS3. If your question is "Why doesn't my border-radius.htc behavior work" that's because behaviors were removed in IE10 for performance and standards-compliance reasons. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh801216(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quirks mode do not support CSS3, and CSS behaviors were [disabled in IE10](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh801216%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). You can set header to `IE=edge` and forget about Quirks mode.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

Look at http://border-radius.com/.

```
-webkit-border-top-left-radius: 10px;
-webkit-border-top-right-radius: 10px;
-moz-border-radius-topleft: 10px;
-moz-border-radius-topright: 10px;
border-top-left-radius: 10px;
border-top-right-radius: 10px;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<!--[if gte IE 9]>
    <style>
        .roundedcorner{
            border-top-right-radius: 20px; 
            border-bottom-right-radius: 20px; 
            border-top-left-radius: 20px;
            border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
        }
    </style>
<![endif]-->
```

OR

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<style>
.roundedcorner{
border-top-right-radius: 20px;
border-top-left-radius: 20px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
}
</style>
```

like

**[DEMO](http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_borders.asp)**

Answer (score 0):

Use browser mode `IE9` with `IE9 standards`. Here the code works fine. Also, there is no need to define each corner as a separate property when they are all `30px`, so just use `border-radius: 30px;`.